# Initializing a xib view as a subview of another NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xib, nib

I'm trying to learn OSX development, and I've created a view in a .xib file, and I'm trying to initialize and then add this view as a subview. I've googled how to do this, and all of the solutions are for iOS and use a call such as `MyViewClass* myViewObject = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyViewClassNib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]`, however it looks like this is not an option for OSX development. Anybody have any ideas on how to initialize the xib as a view? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `loadNibNamed:owner:topLevelObjects:` method. Here's an example:

```
NSArray *views = nil;
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TestView1" owner:nil topLevelObjects:&views];
[self.view addSubview:[views lastObject]];
```

The above code will load the top-level contents of the XIB into an array. Per the documentation:

> Load a nib from this bundle with the specified file name and owner.
>   Upon success, the method returns YES and the optional out-parameter
>   topLevelObjects is populated with the top level objects of the nib.
>   The objects adhere to the standard Cocoa memory management rules and
>   are autoreleased. IBOutlet properties to top level objects should be
>   strong (retain) to demonstrate ownership and prevent deallocation.
>   Alternatively, one may hold a strong reference to the top level
>   objects array.